# What literary term best describes the following phrase relying on the dual meaning of a word for humorous effect?

Tags: puns

"A sheep led astray rarely gets fleeced." The literal act of fleecing of a sheep alludes to the alternative meaning of fleeced - to get swindled, or stripped of money.  It doesn't seem to be a pun, but I can't think of what term would describe the dual literal and figurative meaning of this statement.

Comment: It seems like a [pun](http://literarydevices.net/pun/) (a play on words in which a humorous effect is produced by using a word that suggests two or more meanings or by exploiting similar sounding words having different meanings) to me.

Comment: Fleeced means "to be stripped of" in either context. If there is a double meaning to the phrase, but that double meaning relies on a word meaning the same thing in either context, does that still qualify as a pun?

Answer (score 2):

Double entendre

> a word or phrase open to two interpretations, one of which is usually risqué or indecent.

Comment: BTW OP, "double entendre" is a synonym for "pun".